# raw decoder for protobufs format

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'd like to find a way to convert a binary protobuf message into a human readable description of the contained data, without using the .proto files.

The background is that I have a .proto message that it being rejected by the parser on Android, but it's not entirely clear why. I could go through the message by hand, but it's rather tedious.

I tried `protoc --decode_raw`, but it just gives the error "Failed to parse input.". I google hoping/expecting someone would have done a nice web utility that might do this, but haven't found anything obvious.

I'm just hoping to get some output like:

```
field 1: varint: 128
field 4: string: "foo"
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be most welcome!

Comment: Is there a possibility that the message contains some header attached to it? Try decoding it after skipping the first 1,2,3,4... bytes.

Comment: One of the problem messages was actually only 4 bytes: 18, 4, 48, 0  (decimal). (Maybe it's actually got truncated?)

Comment: 18 = "field 2, length-prefixed" (probably meaning: sub-message), 4 = 4 (the length of the next fragment, in bytes), 48 = "field 6, varint", 0 = 0. So you are missing at least 2 bytes (the advertised sub-message size is not satisfied)

Comment: That would certainly explain why I'm having problems - thanks Marc!

Comment: There is a [related question about non "raw" decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952811/is-there-a-definitive-nix-command-line-tool-for-inspecting-protocol-buffers) (using a known `.proto`).

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914034/how-to-decode-protobuf-binary-response/48868239#48868239

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try forcing it through the wireshark plugin, or you could probably borrow the "reader" part of some of the implementations (I know how I would do this in C#, for example, but I doubt that is what you meant).

However, be cautious - string in protocol buffers doesn't really mean "string" - it could be:

- a UTF-8 string
- a raw BLOB of arbitrary data
- a sub-message
- a "packed" array
- (probably something else I'm forgetting)

Comment: Thanks Marc! I hadn't appreciated that the string and sub-message etc are not distinguishable without the .proto (though I suppose you could make a heuristic based guess)

Comment: @JosephH yeah, you could *try* UTF-8 - you'd get pretty close if it works; the others are trickier though...

Answer (score 39):

For Posterity:
Google's protocol buffer [tools](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list) have the ability to decode raw buffers.

Just send the unknown buffer to it and pass the`--decode_raw` flag

```
$ protoc --decode_raw < has_no_proto.buff
2 {
  2: "Error retrieving information from server. [RH-02]"
}
```

So here's a message with field 2 set to an embedded message which in turn has
its second field set to a string telling me I pissed off Google Play.

Type information isn't definite (it looks like it will try to display all binary data as strings -- but your requirement for varint/string/submessage distinction is met).

Comment: What is the format of the .buff file? I have a binary file containing just the raw protocol buffer bytes but keep getting "Failed to parse input."

Comment: In this case it was raw protocol buffer byte output. Are you certain your file is correct? (look out for magic bytes added by editors)

Comment: @DeepSpace101 maybe you have multiple messages in one file? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34632255/357313

Answer (score 18):

As noted in [Michel de Ruiter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34632255/318428), it's possible that your protobuf message has a [length-prefix](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/02/length-prefix-framing-for-protocol-buffers).  Assuming it does, this answer should help.

(NOTE: For most of the commands below, I'm assuming your protobuf message is stored in a file called `input`.)

### `protoc --decode_raw` + `dd` for a single message:

If it's simply a single message, then you can indeed leverage `protoc --decode_raw`, but you need to strip off the length-prefix header first.  Assuming the header is 4 bytes long you can use `dd` to strip the header off of `input` and then feed the output into `protoc`.

```
dd bs=1 skip=4 if=input 2>/dev/null | protoc --decode_raw
```

### `protoc-decode-lenprefix --decode_raw` for a single message:

I also wrote a [script](https://github.com/erikdw/protoc-decode-lenprefix) that handles the header stripping automatically:

```
protoc-decode-lenprefix --decode_raw < input
```

This script is simply a wrapper on top of `protoc --decode_raw`, but handles parsing out the length-prefix header and then invoking `protoc`.

Now, this script isn't terribly useful in this case, because we can just use the `dd` trick above to strip the header off. However, say we have a data stream (e.g., a file or TCP stream) containing multiple messages that are framed with length-prefix headers....

### `protoc-decode-lenprefix --decode_raw` for a stream of messages:

Instead of a single protobuf message in the input file, let's say `input` contained multiple protobuf messages which are framed by length-prefix headers.  In this case it's not possible to *just* use the `dd` trick, because you need to actually read the contents of the length-prefix header to determine how long the subsequent message in the stream is, and thus how many bytes ahead the next header+message lies.  So instead of worrying about all of that, you can simply use `protoc-decode-lenprefix` again:

```
protoc-decode-lenprefix --decode_raw < input
```

### `protoc-decode-lenprefix --decode ... foo.proto` for a stream of messages

This script can also be used to fully decode length-prefixed messages (instead of just "raw decode" them).  It assumes you have access to the `.proto` files that define the protobuf message, just like the wrapped `protoc` command.  The invocation syntax is identical to `protoc --decode`. For example, using the `dd` trick with `protoc --decode`, along with input being a [Mesos](https://mesos.apache.org/) [task.info](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/0.27.0/src/slave/paths.hpp#L82) file, the syntax looks like this:

```
dd bs=1 skip=4 if=task.info 2>/dev/null | \
protoc --decode mesos.internal.Task \
                      -I MESOS_CODE/src -I MESOS_CODE/include \
                      MESOS_CODE/src/messages/messages.proto
```

And the parameters are identical when using `protoc-decode-lenprefix`

```
cat task.info | \
protoc-decode-lenprefix --decode mesos.internal.Task \
                      -I MESOS_CODE/src -I MESOS_CODE/include \
                      MESOS_CODE/src/messages/messages.proto
```

Answer (score 11):

If you happen to have a binary file containing (multiple?) *length-prefixed* protobuf messages, `protoc ‒‒decode_raw < file` cannot parse it because of the length prefixes. A simple way around that is to split the file into its consecutive messages and *then* convert each with `protoc`.

My take:

```
var fs = File.OpenRead(filename));
var buffer = new byte[4096];
int size;
for (int part = 1; Serializer.TryReadLengthPrefix(fs, PrefixStyle.Base128, out size); part++) {
  long startPosition = fs.Position;
  using (var writer = File.OpenWrite(string.Format("{0}[{1}].pb", filename, part))) {
    for (int bytesToRead = size; bytesToRead > 0; ) {
      int bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(bytesToRead, buffer.Length));
      bytesToRead -= bytesRead;
      if (bytesRead <= 0) // End of file.
        break;
      writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try https://pb-decode.online. I'm the author, suggestions are welcome :)

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be available any more :-(

Comment: @TimPerry Domain expired, plz visit by ip: https://168.138.55.177. If the ip doesn't work, check the [project page](https://github.com/aj3423/aproto) for more information, or just use the offline binary.