# How to decode protobuf binary response

Tags: protocol-buffers, google-goggles

I have created a test app that can recognize some image using Goggle Goggles. It works for me,  but I receive binary protobuf response. I have no proto-files, just binary response. How can I get data from it? (Have sent some image with bottle of bear and got the next response):

```
A
TuborgLogo9 HoaniText���;�)b���2d8e991bff16229f6"�
+TR=T=AQBd6Cl4Kd8:X=OqSEi:S=_rSozFBgfKt5d9b0
+TR=T=6rLQxKE2xdA:X=OqSEi:S=gd6Aqb28X0ltBU9V
+TR=T=uGPf9zJDWe0:X=OqSEi:S=32zTfdIOdI6kuUTa
+TR=T=RLkVoGVd92I:X=OqSEi:S=P7yOhvSAOQW6SRHN
+TR=T=J1FMvNmcyMk:X=OqSEi:S=5Z631_rd2ijo_iuf�
```

need to get string "Tuborg" and if possible type - "Logo"

Comment: What languages do you have at your disposal? there are decoding-stream-readers available in most implementations. I worry, however, about how that data has been encoded. Do you have the actual `byte[]` data? (I ask re the question, as that looks like badly-encoded (aka corrupt) data)

Comment: no, data is ok. I have read response as byte[] array and it jusrt String representation os this data. Below is another response for image with Steve Jobs name:  Z

Steve Jobs Text
#
Manifesto da Morto
Similar Image???;?~Ui4{C~27e437b3469557e98"?
+TR=T=2NKSRNijdzY:X=Op9HS:S=Q5E2GgGTn2FHbvXR
+TR=T=-hAbOrM2yME:X=Op9HS:S=XJ0SUV2EWG1A2Z7O
+TR=T=4fEn46Y2-xM:X=Op9HS:S=xIk9lP93EkhBQroz
+TR=T=-s6bJFuLuRo:X=Op9HS:S=cPnqT3_nWM61zYnv
+TR=T=2hSkrpEoO10:X=Op9HS:S=jsH5Uv1-X9WMQNoN?

Comment: "jusrt String representation os this data" the only "string representations" that could make sense here are: base-64 or hex-encoding. It looks like you are running that through UTF-8 or something, which is ***not valid*** and will lose data. Also, and I repeat: what languages do you have at your disposal?

Comment: I'm using JAVA, here is link to my code (converted it from C# sample) http://prodroid.com.ua/?p=385  Thanks!

Comment: if the response is binary, you ***cannot*** use `readLine` - that is incorrect and will totally corrupt the data. You ***must*** read it as binary.

Comment: yes, I understand, it is just for demonstrations. In real sample I am reading bytes and filling byte[] array. (Then if to print this array as a sting will see data as above)

Comment: @Igor  Have you got any way to do what you have asked ?  I am also facing the same problem as you

Comment: @MarcGravell  Sir i am facing the same problem .Have you any idea how to convert to equivalent string representation in java.

Answer (score 23):

You can decode with `protoc`:

```bash
protoc --decode_raw < msg.bin
```

Comment: how can we do this same thing in java programmatically?

Answer (score 7):

```
UnknownFieldSet.parseFrom(msg).toString()
```

This will show you the top level fields.  Unfortunately it can't know the exact details of field types. long/int/bool/enum etc are all encoded as Varint and all look the same.  Strings, byte-arrays and sub-messages are length-delimited and are also indistinguishable.

Some useful details here: https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js/wiki/How-to-reverse-engineer-a-buffer-by-hand

If you follow the code in the UnknownFieldSet.mergeFrom() you'll see how you could try decode sub-messages and falling back to strings if that fails - but it's not going to be very reliable.

There are 2 spare values for the wiretype in the protocol - it would have been really helpful if google had used one of these to denote sub-messages. (And the other for null values perhaps.)

Here's some very crude rushed code which attempts to produce a something useful for diagnostics.  It guesses at the data types and in the case of strings and sub-messages it will print both alternatives in some cases.  Please don't trust any values it prints:

```
public static String decodeProto(byte[] data, boolean singleLine) throws IOException {
    return decodeProto(ByteString.copyFrom(data), 0, singleLine);
}

public static String decodeProto(ByteString data, int depth, boolean singleLine) throws IOException {
    final CodedInputStream input = CodedInputStream.newInstance(data.asReadOnlyByteBuffer());
    return decodeProtoInput(input, depth, singleLine);
}

private static String decodeProtoInput(CodedInputStream input, int depth, boolean singleLine) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("{ ");
    boolean foundFields = false;
    while (true) {
        final int tag = input.readTag();
        int type = WireFormat.getTagWireType(tag);
        if (tag == 0 || type == WireFormat.WIRETYPE_END_GROUP) {
            break;
        }
        foundFields = true;
        protoNewline(depth, s, singleLine);

        final int number = WireFormat.getTagFieldNumber(tag);
        s.append(number).append(": ");

        switch (type) {
            case WireFormat.WIRETYPE_VARINT:
                s.append(input.readInt64());
                break;
            case WireFormat.WIRETYPE_FIXED64:
                s.append(Double.longBitsToDouble(input.readFixed64()));
                break;
            case WireFormat.WIRETYPE_LENGTH_DELIMITED:
                ByteString data = input.readBytes();
                try {
                    String submessage = decodeProto(data, depth + 1, singleLine);
                    if (data.size() < 30) {
                        boolean probablyString = true;
                        String str = new String(data.toByteArray(), Charsets.UTF_8);
                        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
                            if (c < '\n') {
                                probablyString = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (probablyString) {
                            s.append("\"").append(str).append("\" ");
                        }
                    }
                    s.append(submessage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    s.append('"').append(new String(data.toByteArray())).append('"');
                }
            break;
            case WireFormat.WIRETYPE_START_GROUP:
                s.append(decodeProtoInput(input, depth + 1, singleLine));
                break;
            case WireFormat.WIRETYPE_FIXED32:
                s.append(Float.intBitsToFloat(input.readFixed32()));
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidProtocolBufferException("Invalid wire type");
        }

    }
    if (foundFields) {
        protoNewline(depth - 1, s, singleLine);
    }
    return s.append('}').toString();
}

private static void protoNewline(int depth, StringBuilder s, boolean noNewline) {
    if (noNewline) {
        s.append(" ");
        return;
    }
    s.append('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i <= depth; i++) {
        s.append(INDENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting error `com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)` at input.readTag();

Comment: as a rough guess the point you're reading isn't the start of a protobuf message

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume the real question is how to decode protobufs and not how to read binary from the wire using Java.

The answer to your question can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding)

Briefly, on the wire, protobufs are encoded as 3-tuples of `<key,type,value>`, where:

- the key is the field number assigned to the field in the `.proto` schema
- the type is one of `<Varint, int32, length-delimited, start-group, end-group,int64`. It contains just enough information to decode the value of the 3-tuple, namely it tells you how long the value is.