# Protobuf: raw binary data to json

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

All I have is raw protobuf binary data, I don't have access to .proto file, and I need to convert it to json string in Java. So is there is a way to do that in java? i.e. something similar to protoc tool

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: to be honest, my information about protobuf is limited. I tried several things I found on different tutorials on internet, but I couldn't find any easy way to directly convert say byte array to json. like what protoc --decode_raw is doing

Comment: I don't think you can decode the protobuf without having the .proto schema. You need to know which fields it contains.

Comment: nopes, you can't.

Comment: "protoc --decode_raw" is doing exactly this. I'm thinking there should be away

Comment: @AnthonyJ. The protobuf itself doesn't contain any field names. You can't reconstruct those. What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: similar to protoc output: 12612 {
  1: "http://www.google.com"
  2: 13065730694127675
  4: "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico"
}

Comment: if I can get output like protoc --decode_raw, it will be enough for me. I found one answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937882/parsing-protocol-buffers-without-knowing-the-proto but they guy there built his own binary parser which isn't recommended in my case.

Comment: @AnthonyJ. do you by any chance have the .class/.java files for your proto type? If not, then protobuf is schemaless, and you can only have a guess at the format

Comment: @Michał unfortunately I don't have .class/.java. However, like I said, I'm fine with results like what protoc generates for schemaless protobuf

Comment: @AnthonyJ. In such case, take a look here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream. This implements the majority of the logic from the Python answer you mentioned before. If that answer is correct, you will need to switch on the last 3 bits of the field tag to learn the type. However, be aware of the limitations of this approach as listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343928/2946480. After all, protobuf is a schemaless data format.

Comment: thanks @Michał, I will take a look, it seems it has what i need but requires some work.

Answer (score 4):

This won't be possible without the .proto schema. For multiple reasons:

- the raw binary doesn't include field names, just numbers; you can of course create JSON with integer-looking properties, but:
- the data format is ambiguous without a schema:

  - "varint" (simple integers) can mean multiple different things in different contexts, including signed, unsigned, zig-zag signed, or Boolean
  - ditto for fixed length, which could be integers (signed or unsigned) or floating-point
  - "length prefix" could be a utf-8 string, a packed array, or a sub-message

So: there is simply no good and reliable way of understanding data without the schema, let alone choosing how to display it as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

`.proto` file is basically schema of your proto buffer.

`protoc.exe` tool is used for generating the files (i.e. used for creating the proto buffer by providing setter and getters methods.)

yes their is available some methods which convert the `protobuffer` into `JSON` like i am using `protobuffer` in c++ and it provide some methods to convert it into JSON.

same also will be available in Java as well. so don't mix `protoc` tool concept with this 'data format conversion'

try to use this api provided by Protobuffer offical

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks @Sunny. but I didn't find anything in API to fulfill my needs

Comment: @AnthonyJ. follow the link which i am providing here it will really helpful for you

Comment: sorry but which link? I saw you provided two links, which both are the same. and I couldn't find anything that can just convert raw binary data to json like what protoc is doing. I'm sorry if I'm missing something here

Comment: yes exactly ,These two will help you :-   https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/       https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/

Comment: this are the api's which you have to include in your project and you will be able to do it in `java`

Comment: sorry but why are you posting same link twice? and which API i need to use specifically?

Comment: @AnthonyJ. have you generated `.java` files using `protoc.exe` for `serialization  ` and  `deserialization ` of buffer. check the code generated i.e. java files , and once you have buffer then import the api i.e. `com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat`  class which i am specifying here for conversion of raw binary data i.e. `protocoal buffer` into JSON.

Comment: I see. However, I don't have the .proto files and I know nothing about messages schema. I only have binary data. I used "protoc --decode_raw < raw_binary_proto.bin" command and I got a json as output. I want to do something similar but by java code.

Comment: @AnthonyJ. yes this `Class JsonFormat` used the method `printer` it will return `JsonFormat.Printer` object and then create or build an message of type `MessageOrBuild`  from your raw data i.e. proto data vand then pass that to `print` method of `JsonFormat.Printer` . try this it will help you