# Convert binary file to proto file

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Server returned me binary file -- https://pastebin.com/E4jxdF0W

I want to find .proto structure of the binary file

So, I added the file to the site -- https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode/

And received

[image]

I created proto file (but don't receive valid text)

**What should I change in my proto structure?**

```
syntax = "proto2";

    message Cities {
      repeated City city = 1;
    }
    
    message City {
      optional string name = 2;
      optional string name2 = 3;
      optional string name3 = 4;
      optional string name4 = 5;
      optional string name5 = 6;
      optional string name6 = 7;
      optional int32 name7 = 8;
      optional int32 name8 = 9;
      optional int32 name9 = 10;
      optional string name10 = 11;
    }
```

**UPDATE 1**
I used

```
protoc --decode_raw < binary_file.protobuf
```

And received result

```
1 {
  1: "U\222\017\352c\021\021\346\204\237RT\000\020\266\010"
  2: "\320\241\320\260\320\275\320\272\321\202-\320\237\320\265\321\202\320\265\321\200\320\261\321\203\321\200\320\263"
  4 {
    1: 0x426fc1a3
    2: 0x41f286ea
  }
  5: "\320\241\320\260\320\275\320\272\321\202-\320\237\320\265\321\202\320\265\321\200\320\261\321\203\321\200\320\263"
  5: "\320\241\320\260\320\275\320\272\321\202-\320\237\320\265\321\202\320\265\321\200\320\261\321\203\321\200\320\263\320\260"
  5: "\320\241\320\260\320\275\320\272\321\202-\320\237\320\265\321\202\320\265\321\200\320\261\321\203\321\200\320\263\321\203"
  5: "\320\241\320\260\320\275\320\272\321\202-\320\237\320\265\321\202\320\265\321\200\320\261\321\203\321\200\320\263"
  5: "\320\241\320\260\320\275\320\272\321\202-\320\237\320\265\321\202\320\265\321\200\320\261\321\203\321\200\320\263\320\276\320\274"
  5: "\320\241\320\260\320\275\320\272\321\202-\320\237\320\265\321\202\320\265\321\200\320\261\321\203\321\200\320\263\320\265"
  5: "\320\241\320\260\320\275\320\272\321\202-\320\237\320\265\321\202\320\265\321\200\320\261\321\203\321\200\320\263\320\265"
  6: "sankt-peterburg"
  7: 2
}
2 {
  1: "\224\331\203\202B\303\021\346\224\031RT\000\020\266\010"
  2: "\260\336\t\360I\026I\006\217\232t\2021T\030B"
  3: "\320\237\321\217\321\202\321\221\321\200\320\276\321\207\320\272\320\260"
  4: "https://leonardo.edadeal.io/dyn/re/retailers/images/icons/sq/85cd6908f8a34aefbe66dd1948cc3d39.png"
  5: "https://leonardo.edadeal.io/dyn/re/retailers/images/logos/sq/992af68cffaa47de9ff23079648074ad.png"
  6: "eb2316"
  7: 733
  8: 55
  9: 425
  10: "5ka"
}
2 {
  1: "\224\331\205\336B\303\021\346\224\031RT\000\020\266\010"
  2: "\260\336\t\360I\026I\006\217\232t\2021T\030B"
  3: "\320\224\320\270\320\272\321\201\320\270"
  4: "https://leonardo.edadeal.io/dyn/re/retailers/images/icons/sq/146db05ebc81464cbf4872675cb2e761.png"
  5: "https://leonardo.edadeal.io/dyn/re/retailers/images/logos/sq/9c2b2c291f134929949fa4daab88252f.png"
  6: "FF8A38"
  7: 691
  8: 61
  9: 276
  10: "dixy"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decoding protobuf without schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898230/decoding-protobuf-without-schema)

Answer (score 2):

This is largely trial and error-based, if you can't get the schema. However, I can tell you that the root object here doesn't look like a list (`repeated`) - for that to be true

1. each sub item would have the same field number (they don't, 1 vs 2)
2. each sub item would have the same shape (they don't, see field 4, text vs sub-object)

So your root object has something like:

```proto
optional Foo foo = 1;
optional Bar bar = 2;
```

Comment: And what are types of Foo and Bar?

Comment: @swor I can't tell you the names - the binary content doesn't include that - all I know is that they are different. You'd need to reverse-engineer each separately from the payload. Presumably one of them is the type you've called `City`. The other one is a different shape, so it is something else. I can't speak Russian and I don't know what the context is, so...

Comment: Please, look at UPDATE 1. I found structure of protobuf and I want to create .protoc file based on this knowledge

Comment: @swor which is basically the same content as the screenshot from the website. What is the actual question here? I can't tell you what the fields *are or mean*. There are some obvious text fields, and some integer fields (although I can't tell you whether they are signed or not). A couple of the fields (field 1 in the first message type, and fields 1 and 2 in the second message type) are probably `bytes`, but I can't tell you what the bytes represent.

Comment: @swor btw field 4 in the first message might be a "duration" or "timestamp" (probably a "timestamp" - does April 27th 2005 mean anything?)

Comment: @swor also, 16 bytes suggests "guid"/"uuid", but I can't tell you which endianness/layout (there are multiple conventions in use)

Comment: Can I eliminate the first message?
Second message and others are similar? (only the firstis bad)

Comment: @swor define "eliminate". None of the messages look "bad" to me. If you don't care about the data, sure: you can just ignore it.

Comment: "eliminate" - don't take to account "bad messages". I mean pass these messages and don't parse

Comment: @swor I disagree that they're "bad", but : simply don't define any field 1 on the root message, and you don't need to worry about it (unexpected fields are either skipped or stored in an opaque form for round trip, depending on the implementation)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is outdated, but if you look at the js running on that page there's some code for decoding those objects:

```js
  t.id && t.hasOwnProperty("id") && e.uint32(10).bytes(t.id),
                                null != t.description && t.hasOwnProperty("description") && e.uint32(18).string(t.description),
                                null != t.imageUrl && t.hasOwnProperty("imageUrl") && e.uint32(26).string(t.imageUrl),
                                null != t.priceOld && t.hasOwnProperty("priceOld") && e.uint32(37).float(t.priceOld),
                                null != t.priceNew && t.hasOwnProperty("priceNew") && e.uint32(45).float(t.priceNew),
                                null != t.priceIsFrom && t.hasOwnProperty("priceIsFrom") && e.uint32(48).bool(t.priceIsFrom),
                                t.segmentId && t.hasOwnProperty("segmentId") && e.uint32(58).bytes(t.segmentId),
                                null != t.quantity && t.hasOwnProperty("quantity") && e.uint32(69).float(t.quantity),
                                null != t.quantityUnit && t.hasOwnProperty("quantityUnit") && e.uint32(74).string(t.quantityUnit),
                                null != t.discount && t.hasOwnProperty("discount") && e.uint32(85).float(t.discount),
                                null != t.discountUnit && t.hasOwnProperty("discountUnit") && e.uint32(90).string(t.discountUnit),
                                null != t.discountLabel && t.hasOwnProperty("discountLabel") && e.uint32(98).string(t.discountLabel),
                                null != t.discountPercent && t.hasOwnProperty("discountPercent") && e.uint32(104).uint32(t.discountPercent),
                                null != t.country && t.hasOwnProperty("country") && e.uint32(114).string(t.country),
                                null != t.dateStart && t.hasOwnProperty("dateStart") && e.uint32(122).string(t.dateStart),
                                null != t.dateEnd && t.hasOwnProperty("dateEnd") && e.uint32(130).string(t.dateEnd),
                                t.metaId && t.hasOwnProperty("metaId") && e.uint32(138).bytes(t.metaId),
                                t.compilationIds && t.compilationIds.length)
                                    for (var r = 0; r < t.compilationIds.length; ++r)
                                        e.uint32(146).bytes(t.compilationIds[r]);
                                if (t.brandIds && t.brandIds.length)
                                    for (r = 0; r < t.brandIds.length; ++r)
                                        e.uint32(154).bytes(t.brandIds[r]);
```

maybe that way it's easier to reverse-engineer the protobuf schema.