# Convert protoc generated java files to .proto

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a .java file created by protoc from a .proto file.

The .proto file no longer exists, is there an existing tool to recreate it from the generated .java file?

Comment: Is this answer useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12378656/638028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bottom of the file, you should see a field called `descriptorData` which includes the original descriptor of the proto.   You cannot directly turn this back into a proto file, but it does contain all the information about how to parse the proto.

If you were so inclined, the format of this data is itself a proto, representing a [`descriptor.proto`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto).   You can parse this data yourself and reconstruct it, though I don't think there are any tools to do so automatically.